# Error downloading and installing R packages - pkbrtest

Tags: r, package, r-car

I attempted to install the car and EZanova package in RStudio, but both of them fail and give the following error:

> install.packages('car')
>       Warning in install.packages :
>     dependency 'pbkrtest' is not available
>     % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
>                                    Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
>   100 1434k  100 1434k    0     0  3969k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 3973k
>   tar: Failed to set default locale
>   The downloaded binary packages are in
>       /var/folders/sd/w_vr76v10zd9l734nj0d4zkw0000gn/T//Rtmpb3vqte/downloaded_packages

Anyone has experience solving this error? I have deleted R from my PC (including all packages) and tried to reinstall it, but no luck untill now.

Would be very grateful if anyone has an idea and something I could try.

Comment: The actual problem was the version of R that was installed on the mac, it was too old; check your version by using the function `R.Version()` .
RStudio was updated, but R itself was not...

Answer (score 0):

No need to delete R. The error message suggests that there is an issue in the localization settings your computer is currently using, and how that package or some of its dependencies are expecting a different system locale. You can try this fix by entering in your console:

```
system('defaults write org.R-project.R force.LANG en_US.UTF-8')
```

And then restart R